# Proguard error when try to run with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3, proguard

Someone have a "proguard-maven-plugin" standar maven configuration that can I use for a Enterprise Java Application?, and someone knows what of the 4 pom.xml I need to add the configuration?, I spend a lot of time try to use it but always the maven write:

> Failed to execute goal com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4:proguard (default) on project MavenEnterpriseApp-web: Obfuscation failed (result=1) -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4:proguard (default) on project MavenEnterpriseApp-web: Obfuscation failed (result=1)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Obfuscation failed (result=1)
>       at com.pyx4me.maven.proguard.ProGuardMojo.proguardMain(ProGuardMojo.java:633)
>       at com.pyx4me.maven.proguard.ProGuardMojo.execute(ProGuardMojo.java:486)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)

The proguard configuration that I try:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>proguard</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <inFilter>com.codeInMine.business*</inFilter>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

Comment: I get this too. Nothing says "maven" like a mystery failure with a mystery solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when I updated the maven-assembly-plugin from version 2.1 to version 2.2.2
After changing back to 2.1 it worked again.